# Мусор в статическом списке

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

Я пишу чат. Я использую статический список tempMessages для хранения сообщений в оперативной памяти.

Но каждый раз при перезапуске приложения студии, список заполняется непонятным мусором. Делаю пошаговую отладку, но не понятно откуда этот мусор берется. Каждый раз, как я запускаю пошаговую отладку статический список tempMessages увеличивает свой размер. Подскажите, почему данный список увеличивается?

Код

```
public partial class Messages : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public static List<string> tempMessages = new List<string>();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Message message = new Message();
        message.ReadFromDataBase();
        tempMessages.Add(String.Format("{0}: {1} \n", message.ReceivedDate, message.ReceivedMessage));
        message.DeleteMessageFromDb();
        string formattedText = string.Empty;
        foreach (var tempMessage in tempMessages)
        {
            formattedText += tempMessage;
        }

        chatMenu.InnerHtml = formattedText;
    }
}
public class Message
{
    private string sendedMessage;
    private DateTime sendedDate;
    public string ReceivedMessage { get; private set; }
    public DateTime ReceivedDate { get;  private set; }
    private int messageID;

    public Message()
    {

    }

    public Message(string message)
    {
        sendedMessage = message;
        sendedDate = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public void SaveToDataBase()
    {
        WebChatEntities webChatDb = new WebChatEntities();
        ChatMessage chatMessage = new ChatMessage()
                                      {
                                          ChMessage = sendedMessage,
                                          MessageDate = sendedDate
                                      };

        webChatDb.ChatMessages.AddObject(chatMessage);
        webChatDb.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void ReadFromDataBase()
    {
        WebChatEntities webChatDb = new WebChatEntities();
        var result = from chMessage in webChatDb.ChatMessages
                     let maxDate = webChatDb.ChatMessages.Max(message => message.MessageDate)
                     where chMessage.MessageDate == maxDate
                     select new
                                {
                                    chatMessage = chMessage.ChMessage,
                                    messageDate = chMessage.MessageDate,
                                    ID = chMessage.MessageID
                                };
        foreach (var message in result)
        {
            ReceivedMessage = message.chatMessage;
            ReceivedDate = message.messageDate;
            messageID = message.ID;
        }
    }

    public void DeleteMessageFromDb()
    {
        WebChatEntities webChatDb = new WebChatEntities();
        IEnumerable<ChatMessage> result = from message in webChatDb.ChatMessages
                                          where message.MessageID == messageID
                                          select message;

        foreach (ChatMessage chatMessage in result)
        {
            webChatDb.ChatMessages.DeleteObject(chatMessage);
        }
        webChatDb.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Что понимается под мусором?
2. Зачем хранить сообщения в статическом списке? Как вы собираетесь разграничивать доступ?
   Логично предположить, что после каждого обновления страницы срабатывает событие лоад у страницы, в коде которого вы добавляете в список снова сообщения... Код, который чистит список я не вижу.

К тому же классы доменной модели, которые умеют (имею методы) работать с БД, явно противоречат принципу единой ответственности.

Comment: пустые сообщение понимаются под мусором. С событием лоад я понял. Лучше делать проверку на null? Если сообщение пустое, то не добавлять его в память. Статический список я использую для хранения в оперативной памяти

Comment: Если ваш чат предпологает быть "открытым" (любой пользователь видит все сообщения), то проверка на НУЛЛ скорей всего решит проблему. Я все равно не понимаю логики программы: вы обращаетесь к БД при каждом запросе к данной странице, следовательно зачем вообще сообщения хранить в памяти? Просто вытаскивайте их каждый раз да и все....

Comment: в качестве обратной связи, вопрос я нормальный задал или можно было найти решение самостоятельно?